# read file and store to data structure

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to read a file that looks like this

```
90004    2.050    2.835    12.260    6487.971
90004 1 -0.127 0.109 -0.070 0.068 -2.382 0.514 0.130 1.404 0.950
90004 2 -0.283 0.223 -0.244 0.221 -1.059 0.893 0.213 0.385 0.996
90004 3 -0.120 0.191 -0.082 0.099 -0.192 0.251 4.158 4.233 0.999
90004 4 -0.084 0.136 -0.041 0.040 -0.257 0.419 4.441 4.551 0.999
90004 5 -0.064 0.343 -0.009 0.012 -0.076 0.241 4.096 4.083 1.000
90004 6 -0.089 0.132 -0.032 0.036 -0.214 0.290 4.828 4.986 0.999
```

to do so I created a function

```
def read_file(pulselist,folder):
    for index1 in range(0, len(pulselist)):
        pulse = pulselist[index1]
        filename=str(pulse)+'.txt'

        with open(folder+filename, 'rt') as f_in:
            # print(f.readline())
            lines = f_in.readlines()
            for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                if index == 0:
                    pass
                elif index ==1:
                    Pulse,MAX_IP,MAX_BVAC,MAX_LID3,MAX_TMAX =lines[index].split()
                else:
                    dummy = lines[index].split()
                    info = dummy

        temp_dict=dict(zip(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'], [x for x in info[1:]]))
        temp_dict['pulse'] = int(pulse)
        temp_dict['MAX_IP'] = MAX_IP
        temp_dict['MAX_BVAC'] = MAX_BVAC
        temp_dict['MAX_LID3'] = MAX_LID3
        temp_dict['MAX_TMAX'] = MAX_TMAX
    return temp_dict
```

in this way, I managed to store just the first and last line. I am trying to find a way to store all the lines so that the final dictionary (or any other data structure) have all the information about the lines in the file properly stored.

any help?

Comment: Why can't you do `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: Please show what the end result should be for your input file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
def read_polarimetry_file(pulselist,folder):
    pulse_struct = dict()
    for index1 in range(0, len(pulselist)):
        shot = pulselist[index1]
        filename=str(shot)+'.txt'

        with open(folder+filename, 'rt') as f_in:
            # print(f.readline())
            lines = f_in.readlines()
            channels = {}
            channels.setdefault('A', [])
            channels.setdefault('B', [])
            channels.setdefault('C', [])
            channels.setdefault('D', [])
            channels.setdefault('E', [])
            channels.setdefault('F', [])
            channels.setdefault('G', [])
            channels.setdefault('H', [])
            channels.setdefault('I', [])
            for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                if index == 0:
                    pass
                elif index ==1:
                    Pulse,MAX_IP,MAX_BVAC,MAX_LID3,MAX_TMAX =lines[index].split()
                else:
                    dummy = lines[index].split()
                    info = dummy
                    channels['A'].append(float(info[2]))
                    channels['B'].append(float(info[3]))
                    channels['C'].append(float(info[4]))
                    channels['D'].append(float(info[5]))
                    channels['E'].append(float(info[6]))
                    channels['F'].append(float(info[7]))
                    channels['G'].append(float(info[8]))
                    channels['H'].append(float(info[9]))
                    channels['I'].append(float(info[10]))

            pulse=dict()
            pulse['JPN']=shot
            pulse['MAX_IP']=MAX_IP
            pulse['MAX_BVAC']=MAX_BVAC
            pulse['MAX_LID3']=MAX_LID3
            pulse['MAX_TMAX']=MAX_TMAX
            pulse['channels'] = channels


        pulse_struct[str(shot)]=pulse


    return pulse_struct
```